# Converting from HttpURLConnection TO Retrofit2 Issues

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, gson

I'm upgrading some legacy Android / Java code that pulls in data from a server. The legacy code uses HttpURLConnection and pulls in a inputStream and converts it to a GZipInputStream. The result is then converted to a JSONObject. Then the data is parsed manually. This all works fine, meaning valid json is returned as it starts with '{'

I'm trying to updgrade this code using Retrofit2 and the GsonConverterFactory so I can auto map the json to Classes.

**I'm getting an error:  Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**

This tells me that the data is coming in as a string and not a JSON object.

NOTE: I'm sending the same headers and query parameters for both my legacy code and new Retrofit implementation --- but different result -- can't figure out why.

Comment: This tells you that it expects a `JSONObject` but instead it finds a String. So use the String.class when you use `Gson.from();`

Comment: I'm not using gson  manually. I'm using the GsonConverterFactory

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the server was expecting all of my query parameters to be in one field and the field named "Object" and in a json format i.e: Object={"field1":"fieldOneValue","field2":"fieldTwoValue"} AND had to be Url Uncoded Format:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("testing/myapi.api")
Observable<MyClass> getMyApiData(@Url String url,  @Field("Object") String object);
```